# How to calculate the shortest path between two points characterized by latitude and longitude with pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting

I have to calculate the **length** of the shortest path between A (lat1, long1) and B (lat2, long2). But all the solutions I've found do not get a correct result because they only calculate the distance between the nearest vertex of A to the nearest vertex of B.

Comment: How should your solution behave instead of routing from the nearest vertex? What would be the "correct" result for you?

Comment: The correct result should also consider the distance between point A and its nearest  vertex as well as the distance between point B and its nearest  vertex.

Comment: That will not change the resulting route though. It will only change the total length of the route.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I expressed myself badly. I am interested in having a total length of the route correct!

Comment: closest point on vertex + endpoint/startpoint, use those to create inestring, measure and add total length

Comment: the problem is that everything must be translated into Java code and looking for a single query taking input lat and long performed the task.